Does Microsoft's Windows 11 Home support EFS or other encryption for drives, volumes, or folders (natively)?
I would like to know, conclusively, if Microsoft's Windows 11 Home supports EFS (Encrypting File System AKA Encrypted File System), or any other type of drive, volume, or folder encryption, natively.
I've searched the web for the answer, and different sources offer different answers.  For example, Kapil Arya, who states he is a Microsoft MVP, writes:

As we all know that BitLocker is not available on basic Windows editions, such as Windows 11 Home. So how to encrypt your data if you’re on Windows 11 Home? Well, you can use Device Encryption feature on Windows 11 Home to securely encrypt your data.

source: https://www.kapilarya.com/enable-or-disable-device-encryption-in-windows-11
Kapil doesn't specifically mention EFS in that article, but given that he mentions that he's not referring to BitLocker, my understanding is that he's referring to EFS (please correct me if my understanding is in error).
This information aligns with some sources, but conflicts with others.  An examples of a conflicting source is Geek Rewind, which states:

Encrypted File System is not available on Windows 11 Home Edition.


It’s important to note that the Encrypted File System is unavailable on Windows 11 Home Edition, so users should consider upgrading to Windows 11 Pro for this functionality.

source: https://geekrewind.com/how-to-encrypt-or-decrypt-files-and-folders-with-efs-in-windows-11/
Conclusively, does Microsoft's Windows 11 Home support any drive, volume, or folder encryption natively?  If so, what?

Windows Home does not support EFS. Are you asking about EFS or BitLocker? They are two completely separate and independent Windows features. Your articles about Device Encryption are more relevant to BitLocker than EFS. Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly which feature your asking about

@Ramhound You're right. Thanks. I haven't the time to edit right now, but I'll come back to do.  My meaning is any type of encryption.

Windows 10/11 Home supports a trimmed-down version of BitLocker under the name "Device Encryption". It has no customizability and specific requirements enforced – e.g. you must have TPM available, Secure Boot fully working (can't use PCR4 binding, only PCR7), etc. It is not EFS.
(When those requirements are met, Pro editions sometimes also switch to the "Device Encryption" branding, but retain the option to customize the setup.)

Device Encryption is a Windows feature that enables BitLocker encryption automatically for the Operating System drive and fixed drives.
– https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-encryption-in-windows-cf7e2b6f-3e70-4882-9532-18633605b7df


Device encryption is a Windows feature that provides a simple way for some devices to enable BitLocker encryption automatically. Device encryption is available on all Windows versions, and it requires a device to meet either Modern Standby or HSTI security requirements.
[...] Starting in Windows 11, version 24H2, the prerequisites of DMA and HSTI/Modern Standby are removed.
– https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/#device-encryption

The latter article also says that Device Encryption requires either an Active Directory join (on Pro) or a Microsoft account (on Home/Pro) – both being locations where the recovery key can be backed up without user involvement – before it switches out of "clear key" mode, and that with only a local account it doesn't offer a way to back up the key and activate protection manually. (Of course, on Pro editions you can do that yourself via the full BitLocker UI, but on Home I suspect even manage-bde.exe won't be fully operational.)
EFS (file-level encryption) meanwhile has no hardware or account requirements but is strictly a Pro-only feature as far as I remember.

Wow. This is more confusing than I thought, but you've made it much more clear. Thanks. So Windows 11 Home doesn't offer EFS, but offers a trimmed down version of BitLocker that MS calls "Device Encryption". I'll call that "DE". Does DE work on volumes, or truly only on drives (as in all volumes on the entire drive, or none)? Is there any support for DE on folders or virtual volumes? If you think It would be better for me to post separate questions, I can do that instead of asking here.

@EndAntisemiticHate - DE works on the system disk. You cannot encrypt data volumes (external and internal), if you need that feature, you require BitLocker.  This is all documented by Microsoft of course.
